# Failure to execute maven goal with Jacoco

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I'm trying with more than 15 version on jacoco and still is something wrong.
I've tried with different pom.xml files found on internet, but still without any effects.

Below my pom.xml

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.build</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.5.201403032054</version>
    <relativePath>../org.jacoco.build</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>jacoco</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>JaCoCo :: Distribution</name>
<description>JaCoCo Standalone Distribution</description>
<properties>
    <jarsigner.skip>true</jarsigner.skip>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>${argLine} -Xmx2048m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>${argLine} -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M ${itCoverageAgent}</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.5.201403032054</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-unit-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- prepare agent for measuring integration tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>itCoverageAgent</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>jacoco-${qualified.bundle.version}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-distribution-size</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireFilesSize>
                                <maxsize>2500000</maxsize>
                                <minsize>2100000</minsize>
                                <files>
                                    <file>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-${qualified.bundle.version}.zip</file>
                                </files>
                            </requireFilesSize>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-    plugin:0.6.5.201403032054:check    (default-cli) on project jacoco: The parameters 'rules' for goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.5.201403032054:check are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

And the output depends of version jacoco.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does excluding the `maven-enforcer-plugin` (or its `<configuration>` at the very least) from the `<build>` section make it work? And also specify the commands that you run in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running a specific goal of `jacoco` (the `check` goal to be specific), meaning you are not running any specific `phase` of any `lifecycle`.

Like:

```
mvn jacoco:check
```

Note that your execution `enforce-distribution-size` is bound to the `verify` phase of the `default` lifecycle - so, if you want the execution `enforce-distribution-size` to occur, you should either:

1. run with a phase that is at least `verify` (I assume you don't want to do this) or
2. rename the `<id>` of that `<execution>` to `default-cli` (see [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Default+Plugin+Execution+IDs)), if you require a maven run with specific `jacoco` goal to work, say the `check` goal. Like, change the following line:

`<id>enforce-distribution-size</id>`

to

`<id>default-cli</id>`

That's all you'll need to do.

Comment: I want to make a simple check nothing more. Im typing:

mvn jacoco:check

and

mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:check

but without any effects, even I copied a pom.xml from official page and still nothing, I tried to rename an <id> as You said and nothing.... eh

Comment: Which execution id did you rename? You should be renaming that of the `enforcer-plugin`. Like I'd suggested, take out the `enforcer-plugin` completely out of the `<build>` and see if that helps.

Comment: I added a new plugin ' <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>'

Comment: I don't think you understand what you're doing. If you only want to be able to run `mvn jacoco:check` (instead of running any specific `phase`), you should just rename the execution id of the `enforcer-plugin` to `default-cli`. The change you said you've made in your comment above is wrong - there is no such goal as a `check` in the `enforcer-plugin`. Let me know if you want me to add the exact change to my answer.

Comment: Give me the exact change, please. This problem is new for me and I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: I changed it, it didn't helped